# Hibernate doesn't save parent's id in child table when saving parent

Tags: hibernate, jpa, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

here is my DB structure:

```
details
id, information_id

information
id, name
```

Here is my **Information** entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "information")
data class Information(
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
        val id: Long? = 0,   

        val name: String,

        @OneToOne(cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL), mappedBy = "information")
        val details: Detials? = null
)
```

And here is **Details**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "details")
data class Details(
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
        val id: Long? = null,
        val additionalData: String,

        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "information_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        var information: Information? = null
)
```

And when I'm saving newly created **Information** I want to save id of that entity in **details.information_id** - it's not working now and **details.information_id** is null.

Am I missing some additional annotation parameter? Or my relations are off?
I can first save the **Information** and then get its id and then do an update to **Details** but that's not what I want.

EDIT:
I create my **Information** like that:

```
val information = Information(
                name = "XXXX",
                details = Details(additionalData = "YYYY)
        )
```

and then

```
dao.save(information)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Information.details` contains the `Details` object, but the `Details.information` must also point to the original `Information` object.

Comment: Isn't there an aoption to do that automatically via Hiberante mappngs? I know I could do it but I dont really like this approach

Comment: No, because it can in fact point to a different `Information` object, forming an object chain between the two tables, if that is what your data structure requires. Hibernate is not supposed to decide what your data model is.